# Topological space - Infinite intersection of members

Tags: general-topology

The definition of Topological Space via open sets is :

```
A topological space is an ordered pair (X, τ), where X is a set and τ is a                   
collection of subsets of X, satisfying the following axioms:

-The empty set and X itself belong to τ.
-Any (finite or infinite) union of members of τ still belongs to τ.
-The intersection of any finite number of members of τ still belongs to τ.
```

Why the intersection of any **infinite** number of members of τ is neglected by the definition ?

Comment: To get things started: the general notions in topology should incorporate classical theory as a special case. In the real line, the infinite intersection of the open sets $(-1/n,1/n)$ is $\{0\}$ and, hence, not open.

Comment: [see this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284970/in-a-topological-space-why-the-intersection-only-has-to-be-finite)

Comment: Further, any closed interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ is equal to the intersection $\cap (a - \frac{1}{n}, b + \frac{1}{n})$

Comment: What do you think that an axiom should say about an intersection of an infinite number of members of $\tau$?

Answer (score 0):

Of course we are free to define what we want, and we could define a $\ast$-topological space as a pair $(X, \tau)$ satisfying the axioms of a topological space *plus* the stronger axiom that the intersection of *any number* of members of $\tau$ belongs to $\tau$.

However, this concept is not useful. For example, $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology (open sets are unions of open intervals) is not a $\ast$-topological space.

You probably know that topological spaces can alternatively introduced via closed sets, i.e. as pairs  $(X, \alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following axioms:

- The empty set and $X$ itself belong to  $\alpha$.
- Any intersection of members of $\alpha$ belongs to  $\alpha$.
- Any union of finitely many members of  $\alpha$ belongs to  $\alpha$.

Given  $\alpha$, the set $\tau = \{ X \backslash A \mid A \in \alpha \}$ is a topology on $X$. Simililarly it works in the other direction.

In a $\ast$-topological space the union of *any number* of closed sets is a closed set. This is a very serious restriction. For example, if you want that all singletons $\{ x \}$, $x \in X$ are closed (which is the case in most topological spaces occurring in practical applicatons), then all subsets are closed which means that the space $X$ has the discrete topology (all sets are open).