# The axioms of topology

Tags: general-topology, intuition

I am just curious about the axioms of topology. In particular with regard to finite intersections. The way that I imagine the axioms of topology is that we give a set $X$ a way of arranging it's points. I was wondering why do we restrict ourself to only finite intersections. Does someone has any intuition about this?

Comment: An infinite intersection can "collapse" onto a "closed" limit point.  If $A_n = (-\frac 1n, \frac 1n)$ then $\cap_{i\in\mathbb N} A_i = \{0\}$ not an open set.  Or $B_n =(-\frac 1n, 1 +\frac 1n)$ the $\cap_{i\in\mathbb N} B_n = [0,1]$.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I was guessing. Thanks for clarifying and also pining that down!

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2884822.